# Fill a Javascript-Array within a Fluid foreach

Tags: javascript, typo3, flux, fluid

i try to create a js-array with a fluid-foreach but i just get the "{obj.background.title}" output. when i put it in a console.log it works.

```
<script>
    <f:for each="{settings.backgrounds}" as="obj" iteration="itemIteration">
        {f:if(condition: itemIteration.isFirst, then: 'var backgrounds = [')}
            {
                    src: "fileadmin/user_upload/configurator_1/background1.jpg",
                    isdark: true,
                    title: "{obj.background.title}",
            },
        {f:if(condition: itemIteration.isLast, then: ']')}
    </f:for>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `f:format.raw` around the opening or closing curly braces. This prevents the Fluid parser from seeing it as an inline accessor.

Comment: this would inhibit Fluid from inserting the template variable at {obj.background.title} IMHO

Comment: It would not inhibit the insertion of variables, nor calls to other ViewHelpers. That ViewHelper disables escaping, not parsing. The point in this case is to prevent the parser from seeing the entire expression as an inline (object accessor) syntax chunk. We do this by intentionally disrupting the pattern around either the first or last curly brace - repeat for as many nested curly braces as you have. Please note that this isn't necessary in all cases, just the specific cases where the entire block can be detected as Fluid.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript-`{` probably confuses the Fluid parser (off topic: what a catastrophic idea to use a JavaScript syntax token in an HTML templating engine and even forget about a clean way to escape it!).

That said it is sadly very common for JavaScript-in-Fluid to be parsed half-way or not at all or anything in between (as you just experienced). I used to use `f:format.cdata()` but even that has caveats. It often depends on the position of your `<script>` in the template so moving it more to the end of your template might help if you want to go the trial-and-error path...

I recommend passing over dynamic data to JavaScript by assigning the whole JavaScript to a template variable in your controller and outputting it via `{script -> f:format.raw()}`. This means ugly frontend-related stuff in your controller but it is the quickest and a very reliable way.

Or you can use a vhs-ViewHelper to convert your data to JSON and assign a HTML-data-property and process it via an external JavaScript logic. This also works reliably and is quite clean in my eyes.

In Fluid:

```
<x-mytag data-backgrounds="{v:format.json.encode(value: setting.backgrounds)}" />
```

Ideally in an external JavaScript (actually, this would even work inside Fluid):

```
var backgrounds = JSON.parse(
  document.querySelector('[data-backgrounds]').dataset.backgrounds
)
```

Everybody made this experience once... I am very open to learn about other approaches.

Comment: There is, as you can see from my answer above, a completely valid way to escape such expressions. I should also correct the misunderstanding that Fluid is only an HTML templating engine - it is not. It is an "anything" template engine. It uses XML syntax for nodes, but the fact that you are putting JavaScript into it means you have to take precautions. Just like if you put unescaped entities into an XML document; except Fluid is unfortunately not able to detect that you wanted that specific code to NOT be Fluid and present a relevant error. It is not psychic; and it favors ignoring unknowns.